# Printing the days of the week for every day this year

Tags: c, datetime, portability

@chux pointed out that [my attempted solution](/a/102656/9357) contained several problems.  Since I screwed that up so badly, I figure that I should put my revised solution up for review.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

/**
 * The current year (number of years since 1900)
 */
static int this_year(void) {
    time_t now = time(NULL);
    struct tm thetime;
    localtime_r(&now, &thetime);
    return thetime.tm_year;
}

static struct tm jan1(int yy) {
    struct tm t = { 0 };
    t.tm_year = yy;
    t.tm_mday = 1;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    return t;
}

int main(void) {
    int yy = this_year();

    for (struct tm t = jan1(yy); mktime(&t), t.tm_year == yy; t.tm_mday++) {
        char buf[80];
        if (!strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%m/%d/%Y is a %A", &t)) {
            return 1;   // Unexpected failure
        }
        puts(buf);
    }
}
```

Concerns include standards compliance, portability, and correctness in all possible time zones.  If possible, a more succinct way to obtain the current year and January 1 of the current year would be appreciated.

Comment: @Quill Agree the overall task is more of calendar systems than time zones, but usage of functions `time()` and then `mktime()` offer no separation of calendar systems and time zones.  Either neither with `time()` or both with `mktime()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Functionality**

Code needs to set `t.tm_isdst = -1;` before calling `mktime(&t)` each day to avoid only advancing only 23 hours.

```
setenv("TZ", "America/Sao_Paulo", 1);
tzset();
...
    for (struct tm t = jan1(yy); mktime(&t), t.tm_year == yy; t.tm_mday++) {
        char buf[80];
        if (!strftime(buf, sizeof buf, "%m/%d/%Y%z is a %A", &t)) {
            return 1;   // Unexpected failure
        }
        puts(buf);
    }

02/20/2015-0200 is a Friday
02/21/2015-0200 is a Saturday
02/21/2015-0300 is a Saturday
02/22/2015-0300 is a Sunday
```

**Data abstraction**

Even though `struct tm` references the year 1900, a function called `this_year()` should either use a more neutral epoch or be renamed.  Since this is a `static` function - used only locally, not a strong need for this.

```
int this_year(void)  // Return 2015 for this year
int this_year_since_1900(void)  // Return 115 for this year
```

**Generality**

If this was not a `static` function, but for general use, `tm jan1()` should returned a `struct tm` with all its fields in a consistent state.

```
static struct tm jan1(int yy) {
    struct tm t = { 0 };
    t.tm_year = yy;
    t.tm_mday = 1;
    t.tm_isdst = -1;
    mktime(&t); // Add to up_date tm_isdst, tm_yday, tm_wday and other optional fields.
    return t;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The only thing I have to say is that the use of `strftime` and `%A` means that the output will depend on the current locale setting.

This may be a bug or a feature depending on what your original intention was.

Also, the use of `char buf[80]` seems rather small for today's processors. The only way that `strftime` is going to fail is if it can't fit all of the output in the buffer. Since memory is cheap, you might as well make it `char buf[256]` or `buf[1024]`. This kinda of ties in with with the question of whether you expect to use this with custom locales.

Alternatives:

- use `strftime_l` to use a specific locale
- create your own array of weekday names instead of `%A` and use the `tm_wday` field to index into that array